# Can you patent a card game?

Tags: australia, intellectual-property, patents

I have created a card game, the idea is somewhere between poker and slots. I hope to create a website to monetise the game but do not know whether I am able to patent the game in order to stop big companies from stealing the game. How effective is a patent at protecting a card game? Also, if so, then must I patent all small variants of the game also? It should be noted that I am from Australia where gambling websites are legal. Thanks.

Comment: You might try these questions at http://patents.stackexchange.com/ -- especially the practical ones.

Comment: @Tom, What do you mean by the phrase "gambling websites are legal" and to what *extent* are they legal?

Comment: While US related (and board rather than card game), you may wish to read of [7,264,242](http://www.google.com/patents/US7264242) which [has been going around in court for the past few years](http://www.law360.com/articles/649421/fed-circ-slashes-innovention-s-4-7m-game-patent-award) over the size of the damages owed (if it was willful infringement or not - that it infringed isn't in doubt). The judgment is against MGA Entertainment which is a Very Large Company. So yes, it can protect against big companies stealing the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

The [AusPat database](http://www.ipaustralia.gov.au/auspat/index.htm) is an excellent source for looking for Australian patents. I did a quick search for ["card game"](http://pericles.ipaustralia.gov.au/ols/auspat/quickSearch.do?queryString=card+game&resultsPerPage=) and came across 276 results fitting those keywords. Not all involve the classic generic-52-card-deck format, but some do.

A good example - and one that seems similar to your idea - is ["Modified blackjack game using non-standard blackjack card values"](http://pericles.ipaustralia.gov.au/ols/auspat/applicationDetails.do?applicationNo=2014901074), by Davinder Signh Sandhu. There's no direct link to it from AusPat.<sup>1</sup>

So yes, you can patent a card game in Australia.

At the moment, I don't have enough information to answer your other two questions.

---

<sup>1 I found [a similar American patent](http://encrypted.google.com/patents/US5979897) with more information, though I have no proof that the two are in similar formats.</sup>

Comment: He mentioned to put the game online... surely your answer should tackle international concerns (because a competitor would be located overseas) instead of limiting yourself to "Australian patents"?

Answer (score 2):

While many card games are patented in the U.S., it has been almost impossible to patent a card game or a board game in the last few years. The movement against software patents has resulted in a very broad application "abstractness" being used as a rejection, even though the courts have not defined it.